# Reinforcing a high load wooden corner shelf

Tags: shelving

I would like to build a shelf capable of holding a maximum load of cca. 60Kg. The image show the placement of the shelf.

[image]

Below is a conceptual drawing with the dimensions.

[image]

The image shows the [brackets](http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mk7iyM-QSEumktBuzBsqHOQ.jpg) serving as the main support for the shelf. They are capable of carrying far more than 60Kg but have a limited width.

This makes the "critical surface", the weakest link of the construction and the part most prone to breaking.

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I think you need bigger brackets. Otherwise I'd consider ...

- Make the wood thick
- Select a strong species
- Align the grain *across* the width (less chance of 40cm splitting off)
- Extend the brackets using ~60cm pieces of wood as an intermediate support.
- Screw a support rail along the wall up to the window.